# How to drag a Farseer body with the mouse, without springiness?

Tags: xna, drag, farseer

I am using Farseer and XNA.
I'm trying to drag an body with the mouse, but I don't want a spring behavior,
like in the demos.I want the object to follow the mouse very closely and without
 springiness, but still be able to rotate.

I tried using another invisible body attached with a RevoluteJoint and moving that,
but that still has a little bit of spring to it, and the dragged body lags behind 
the mouse a bit.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make the spring very stiff ... don't fight against the physics engine, just model the physical properties to emulate the behavior you want to display.